# How does the Linux kernel get info about the processors and the cores?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Assume we have a blank computer without any OS and we are installing a Linux. Where in the kernel is the code that identifies the processors and the cores and get information about/from them?
This info eventually shows up in places like /proc/cpuinfo but how does the kernel get it in the first place?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Short answer*

Kernel uses special CPU instruction [`cpuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) and saves results in internal structure - [`cpuinfo_x86`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.12#L83) for x86

*Long answer*

Kernel source is your best friend.
Start from entry point - file `/proc/cpuinfo`. 
As any proc file it has to be cretaed somewhere in kernel and declared with some file_operations. This is done at [fs/proc/cpuinfo.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/cpuinfo.c?v=3.12). Interesting piece is `seq_open` that uses reference to some `cpuinfo_op`. This ops are declared in [arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c?v=3.12#L152) where we see some `show_cpuinfo` function. This function is in the same file on [line 57](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c?v=3.12#L57).

Here you can see

```c
 64         seq_printf(m, "processor\t: %u\n"
 65                    "vendor_id\t: %s\n"
 66                    "cpu family\t: %d\n"
 67                    "model\t\t: %u\n"
 68                    "model name\t: %s\n",
 69                    cpu,
 70                    c->x86_vendor_id[0] ? c->x86_vendor_id : "unknown",
 71                    c->x86,
 72                    c->x86_model,
 73                    c->x86_model_id[0] ? c->x86_model_id : "unknown");
```

Structure `c` declared on the first line as `struct cpuinfo_x86`. This structure is declared in [arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.12#L83). And if you search for references on that structure you will find function [`cpu_detect`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c?v=3.12#L574) and that function calls function `cpuid` which is finally resolved to [`native_cpuid`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.12#L189) that looks like this:

```c
189 static inline void native_cpuid(unsigned int *eax, unsigned int *ebx,
190                                 unsigned int *ecx, unsigned int *edx)
191 {
192         /* ecx is often an input as well as an output. */
193         asm volatile("cpuid"
194             : "=a" (*eax),
195               "=b" (*ebx),
196               "=c" (*ecx),
197               "=d" (*edx)
198             : "" (*eax), "2" (*ecx)
199             : "memory");
200 }
```

And here you see assembler instruction [`cpuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID). And this little thing does real work.

Comment: A brilliant answer. Exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This information from BIOS + Hardware DB. You can get info direct by dmidecode, for example (if you need more info - try to check dmidecode source code)

```
sudo dmidecode -t processor
```